# How much of male parental matter is still there in an infant organism after birth?

Tags: genetics

Are the atoms from the father's sperm still there in his baby's cells? Do they get lost during pregnancy? If they are still there, are they in a particular cell? Are they dispersed among many cells? Is it a regular mechanism or a matter of chance?

Comment: What do you mean by the term - "The atoms from father's sperm"? Is it chemical atoms or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most animals, humans included, the normal pattern of fertilization ends up with precisely one sperm contributing precisely two things to the egg: [a haploid nucleus and a centriole](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26843/). That's it. No more physical matter from the father ever enters the baby.

A typical human nucleus is about [a 6 micron sphere of material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_nucleus#Structures), and a centriole is much smaller, so we're talking about mass in the picogram range. A healthy newborn child is a little over 3 kilograms, so the fraction of paternal atoms in a newborn child is definitely less than $10^{-12}$.

The actual location of those atoms would be fairly arbitrarily dispersed with each cell division, with the biggest chunks being the chromosomes and centriole, which could end up in at most 24 different cells. Don't forget, however, that not all cells in the fetus make it to the baby (some die, some are shed or otherwise disposed of), so some of that paternal matter might well be further lost. Other paternal atoms will be in materials less carefully managed by the cell (e.g., non-chromosomal materials of the haploid nucleus), and so will disperse more evenly and also be diluted by the regular processes of recycling and dilution.

Bottom line: there will likely be a few atoms from the father in the child, but only a vanishingly small fraction.  That doesn't really matter, though, because the *information* contributed from the father is still in every cell.

Comment: The father contributes information just once, doesn't he?

Comment: Yes, via that one sperm. The mother also contribute genetic information just once, via the egg (which has a little more genetic information than the sperm, due to the addition of mitochondria). The mother also has, of course, a major impact on development by providing the gestational environment, but the information content of that is difficult to define.

Comment: Doesn't the mother contribute genetic information as many times as there cells in the embryo and then in the foetus?

Comment: @yewgeniy No: just the once, via the egg, just like the father does just the once via the sperm. After that, the genetic information of both gets replicated. The _atoms_ come from the mother (or, more properly, mostly from her food, delivered to the growing fetus by her body), but they no more deliver genetic information than your dinner gives to you.

Comment: "... the genetic information... gets replicated..." by whom?

Comment: Cells replicate themselves.